# Custom Decodable type that can be an Array or a String

Tags: swift, codable, decodable

An API I deal with returns either:

```
{
  "title": "Hello World"
}
```

or

```
{
  "title": [{
    "text": "Hello World"
  }]
}
```

My idea would be to have a `struct TitleStringValue` which has a custom decoder, like this:

```
struct TitleStringValue: Decodable {
    let text: String
    
    struct TitleStringValueInner: Decodable {
        let text: String
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        if let stringContainer = try? decoder.singleValueContainer() {
            text = try stringContainer.decode(String.self)
        } else {
            var arrayContainer = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
            text = try arrayContainer.decode(TitleStringValueInner.self).text
            while !arrayContainer.isAtEnd {
                _ = try? arrayContainer.decode(TitleStringValueInner.self)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyResult: Decodable {
  let title: TitleStringValue
}
```

But in the case where title is composed of an array, the TitleStringValue `init(from decoder: Decoder)` is never called as the decoder fails before, encountering an array where it expects a single value type.

Is there a way to solve this?

I could implement decode on the level of my MyResult struct, but that means that each struct that has `TitleStringValue`s needs a custom decoder, so I would much rather implement it on TitleStringValue-level.

Comment: See my comment at the end: I could implement it there but that means that each struct that has TitleStringValues needs a custom decoder. I'll change the name of Data to MyResult, you're right that may be confusing.

Comment: An array means that it can potentially have multiple elements. What do you want to decode as `text` when it's something like `[{"text": "title1"}, {"text": "title2"}]`?

Comment: @Sweeper then I want to decode title1, see while loop ignoring other results. Question has been answered in the mean time, see accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that singleValueContainer can be used to decode also an array. So, the error that you are getting is produced by the second `try` inside `init(from:)` function of `TitleStringValue` and not before.

Having said that, you can further simplify your custom decoding like this:

```
struct TitleStringValue: Decodable {
    let text: String
    
    struct TitleStringValueInner: Decodable {
        let text: String
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let string = try? container.decode([TitleStringValueInner].self).first?.text {
            text = string
        } else {
            text = try container.decode(String.self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha so I made the wrong assumption. This works like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to keep the `title` property for both cases.

First try to decode a `String`. If this fails decode an array of `Text` (I kept the names simple) get the first item und assign the `text` value to `title`.

```
struct Title: Decodable {
    
    struct Text : Decodable { let text : String }
    
    let title : String
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case title }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        do {
            title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            let textArray = try container.decode([Text].self, forKey: .title)
            title = textArray.first?.text ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```